# What is wrong with my regex trying to fix invalid SQL ?

Tags: java, regex

In some case I will have an invalid SQL query

```
select
        foo  as foo,
        bar  as bar,
    from
      ...
```

Note the comma before the from.

Now I tought it would be easy to detect when a comma is before the from with a regex and replace it...

I tryed

```
query.replaceAll("(?s)\\, *\\n* *from", "(\\n) from")
```

- It is possible to have multiple break line this explain the `\\n*`
- It is possible to have mutiple spaces after the comma this explain the `\\, *`
- It is possible to have spaces before **from** this explain the `*from`

Now I'm trying to replace that with a break line followed by **from** as you can see.

But nothing is replaced, what am I missing ?

Comment: When you say nothing is replaced, I do assume you are doing `query = query.replaceAll("(?s)\\, *\\n* *from", "(\\n) from")`, right?

Comment: wouldn't it be better to ... not have that ',' in the first place, instead of inline trying to fix the issue?

Comment: @JoshM Yes, I'm used to regex replacement..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
,\s*from
```

Try this.Replace with `\nfrom`.see demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/26

**Edit :** since this is tagged as Java, use `System.getProperty("line.separator") + " from"` for replacement instead of `\nfrom`.